# Select query issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following data in a table:

```
Date       ID             Start                   END        Duration_S     Duration_A
9/12/2011 22216 9/12/2011 12:30:00 PM   9/12/2011 2:15:00 PM    6300         NULL
9/12/2011 22216 9/12/2011 2:30:00 PM    9/12/2011 2:39:00 PM    540           NULL
9/12/2011 22216 9/12/2011 5:20:00 PM    9/12/2011 5:50:00 PM    1800           NULL
```

My goal is to update the Duration_A column, currently Null.

The information I use to get that info is a table structured like so:

```
ID        Start_Time    State   End_Time       State_Duration
22216   6/3/10 2:07:58  1      6/3/10 2:20:58       800
22216   6/3/10 2:21:58  2      6/3/10 2:25:55       52
22216   6/3/10 5:21:58  2      6/3/10 5:31:05       600
```

To update my Duration_A, I have to sum the duration containing certain states(this is no problem), but the issue is that the Start_Time and End_Time have to match the Start and End of my first table. Here is what I am doing:

```
SELECT     tblB.ID, SUM(tblB.StateDuration) AS Total, tblA.Start_Time, 
                      tblA.End_Time
FROM         
                      tblA INNER JOIN tblB ON tblB.Id = tblA.ID
                      tblB.Start_Time >= tblA.Start AND 
                      tblB.End_Time <= tblA.End

WHERE     STATE IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11)
GROUP BY tblB.StateDuration, tblB.Id, tblA.Start_Time, 
                      tblA.End_Time,tblB.End_Time, 
                      tblB.Start_Time
```

This gives me the first duration when the start and end time of tblB match tblA, where I want the sum of all durations between those time frames. If I am not clear, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand you don't need to group by all there fields. Just add more conditions into the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT     tblB.ID, SUM(tblB.StateDuration) AS Total, tblA.Start_Time, 
                      tblA.End_Time
FROM         
                      tblA INNER JOIN tblB ON tblB.Id = tblA.ID
                      tblB.Start_Time >= tblA.Start AND 
                      tblB.End_Time <= tblA.End

WHERE     STATE IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11) AND 
          tblA.Start_Time <= tblB.Start_Time AND 
          tblB.End_Time <= tblA.End_Time
GROUP BY tblB.id
```

Comment: I made some modifications. Please check the latest version

Comment: If I do not group by what I posted, it throws me an error saying I must group them.

Comment: I added some fields to group also, and using your example it works. Thank you Oleg!

Comment: @Oleg Whe you use `GROUP BY`, every item in the `SELECT` statement has to be either a.) be in the `GROUP BY` statement, or b.) have an aggregate function (like SUM) being applied to it in the `SELECT`.  `Start_Time` and `End_Time` are not valid in the `SELECT` because they don't meet either requirement, thus this query will throw errors as-written (like the OP said it did)